# Google Dynamic Delivery INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

Tags: android, app-bundle

I can download success and it also return installed success result.But i am getting the following error:

```
E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.cq.k.onReceive(20): Error -504 while installing pkgname.pkgname.pkgname: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/pkgname.pkgname.pkgname-S4Ty06YpxYgYiWkxtqNmWw==: Package /data/app/pkgname.pkgname.pkgname-S4Ty06YpxYgYiWkxtqNmWw==/split_dynamic_name.apk code is missing
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

finally i fix it.
enable multiDex support